# How to create Generic event handler with React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a component called `Button` which accepts the `onChange`props. Right now the type of `onChange: event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` and working fine. I want to create a `union type` of expecting the following two types. I wanted to do something like this which makes this `onChange` generic type.

```
import React from 'react';

type handleChange = (value: string,checked: boolean,name: string) => void 
 
type eventHandleChange = <T extends HTMLElement>(
  event: React.ChangeEvent<T>
) => void;

type Change = handleChange | eventHandleChange;

type buttonProps ={
  onChange?: Change
}

export const Button =(Props:buttonProps) =>{
  
  //code here

}
```

But when I am trying to pass a function to props like this one it's giving me an error

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../button';

export const FooComponent=()=>{

  const changHandler = (event: React.ChangEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
   setSelectedValue(event.targe.value)
  }

  return (
    <Button onChange={changeHandler} />
  )
}
```

**ERROR**

```
'(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'eventHandleChange | handleChange | undefined'.
   
Type '(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'eventHandleChange'.
 
Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.       
Type 'ChangeEvent<T>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.         
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.           
Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 49 more.
```

As `HTMLInputElement` is extends from `HTMLElement` `T` Should be generic here for all `HTMLElement`. I am not sure what I am missing here in implemantation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might think of as "broader" and "narrower" get reversed when dealing with callbacks.  In order to assign A to B, where A and B are both callbacks, A has to accept all of the types that B accepts.  If A only accepts a specific subset of what B does, then it's not assignable to B.

Here, you have a type `eventHandleChange` that can handle the change on any `HTMLElement`.  The callback which you are trying to assign to it only accepts the change event for `HTMLInputElement`, so it is not assignable.

One possible way to fix this is by moving the generic `T` higher up the chain so that we can say that `buttonProps` can take a very specific callback.

```
type handleChange = (value: string, checked: boolean, name: string) => void

type eventHandleChange<T extends HTMLElement> = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<T>
) => void;

type Change<T extends HTMLElement> = handleChange | eventHandleChange<T>;

type buttonProps = {
  onChange?: Change<HTMLInputElement>
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/DWKZZm)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a type that accepts any type of HTML Element you can use:

```
type AnyHTMLElement = HTMLElementTagNameMap[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]
```

If it comes from querySelector or ref you may need to add  `| null` to the definition